# How to disable $window.alert function in AngularJS controller from coming on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to stop the alert coming in my dashboard any suggestions?
Thank you!

I tried to override the function `alert empty` in my controller but still, I'm getting the `window alert` when I execute my page.

```
$window.alert = function() {};
```

I even deleted the `$window.alert();` from the `controller.js` but no use.

Comment: Why does the alert appear at all? Maybe something is not calling `$window.alert` but `window.alert`?

Comment: Can you please tell from where the alert is getting triggered?

Comment: previously I added the $window.alert for debugging and now I deleted it but still its appearing during the execution. Maybe it is like you are saying but how to stop this alert function()   @scipper

Comment: Its getting called from Controller.js in one of my functions @Krunal

Comment: If you removed the `$window.alert` and it still pops up, be sure that you are executing the correct code/compiled successfully/saved your changes/cleared your browser cache. Just fighting the symptoms is bad practice; go find the reason.

Comment: I did what You are saying @scipper before I post my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you can replicate your problem, but try to use `$event.stopPropagation()` where you need to stop even actions.